# Viewport Statistics & FPS display permanent

Tags: 3d-view

I think it's important to always see statistics for vertices/faces count overall, and also for the selected object, and always the viewport fps . And yes it exist statistics, but its unfortunately not enough. E.g. you wanna make a huge scene. So need to always see the fps performance of the viewport, so you can optimize the scene. And if suddenly the fps drops, you would know why.

I've searched a lot and maybe I'm blind, but is somewhere really an option or is somewhere an addon for that?

Otherwise I would try to mod it in. What is best page for starting in Add-on scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall vertex and face counts can be shown always in the status bar at the bottom of the Blender window.  Right click on the bar to bring up this menu:

[image: Status bar statistics menu]

and select what you want to see.  The output is in the lower right and looks like this:

[image: typical output]

FPS is shown in the 3D viewport but only when you're running an animation. It's display is enabled in preferences:

[image: fps display highlighted in preferences]

I don't think you can mod this by an add-on script as those statistics are produced in the C code; but if you want to start writing add-ons, there's a tutorial on the Blender Studio web site called ["Scripting for Artists"](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/) and a very simple [add-on tutorial](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) in the manual.  (You can also find most of the scripting tutorial on YouTube.)